# Variably modified type in C language

Tags: c

Can anyone explain what a variably modified type is?

> *If we have an array `a[n]` and `n` is not known at compile time then `a` is a VLA.  Given an array `b[c][d]` where `c` and `d` are not known until runtime implies `b` is a VLA, right?*

In my book they have said that a variably modified type contains a VLA.
That's it; nothing more.

How do I create a pointer to a variably modified type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variably-modified type is the type of a VLA (variable length array). There's a similar type in a structure with a flexible array member, but I don't plan to discuss flexible array members further.

The key point about a VLA is that the dimension of an array is not known until run-time.  Classically, in C89 and before the standard, all dimensions of an array except the first had to be a known constant value at compile time (and the first dimension could be specified as `int a[]` or `int b[][SIZE]` or `int c[][SIZE1][SIZE2]` where the sizes are constants).

```
void some_function(int n)
{
    int a[n];
    int c = n+1;
    int d = n+2;
    int b[c][d];
    another_function(n, a, c, d, b);
    ...
}

void another_function(int n, int a[n], int c, int d, int b[c][d])
{
    ...
}
```

Both `a` and `b` are variable length arrays.  Prior to C99, you could not have written `some_function()` like that; the size of the arrays would have to be known at compile time as compile-time constants.  Similarly, the notation for `another_function()` would not have been legal before C99.

You could, and still can (for reasons of backwards compatibility, if nothing else) write a moderate simulation of `another_function()`:

```
enum { FIXED_SIZE = 32 };

void yet_another_function(int a[], int n, int b[][FIXED_SIZE], int c)
{
    ...
}
```

This isn't a perfect simulation because the FIXED_SIZE is a fixed size, but the pure C99 VLA code has a variable dimension there.  Old code would often, therefore, use a FIXED_SIZE that was large enough for the worst case.

Inside `another_function()`, the names `a` and `b` are basically pointers to variably modified types.

Otherwise, you do it the same as for a fixed size array:

```
int z[FIXED_SIZE];
int (*z_pointer)[FIXED_SIZE] = &z;

int v[n];
int (*v_pointer)[n] = &v;
```

Comment: A structure with a flexible array member is not a variably modified type. See N1570 6.7.6p3 for the definition.

Comment: OK; I'd not checked -- modified to match your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @KeithThompson Does it mean that a variably modified type is a VLA _only_?

Comment: Consider: `sizeof( int[R][C])` . Do you see any array in there? I don't. That is VMT. Variably Modified Type.

Comment: @ChefGladiator— I wasn't writing the C standard; such precision was not required.  Yes, in `sizeof(int[R][C])` you have a VMT, but its size is the size that an object of the VMT would have, and the object would be a VLA, so colloquially it is an array (type).

Comment: Then please change your first sentence. Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

VLA == Variable Length Array

Variable Length Arrays were introduced in the C99 spec to allow for things like this:

```
int someArraySize;
int myArray[someArraySize];
```

Variably Modified type is the type of a Variable Length Array. Thus, a Variably Modified type CONTAINS a VLA. In the case of your example of b[c][d] where c and d are not known until run time, b is a Variably Modified type that happens to be a Variable Length multi-dimensional array. b[c][d] is a variable length array of variable length arrays-- phew, what a mouthful.

Here is a great source I found that describes these VLAs and the Variably Modified type with examples:

http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/dont-be-afraid-of-variably-modified-types/

Comment: Almost right.  VMT can not "contain" an array. VMT != VLA. Yes that Gustedt text explains VMTs and VLAs rather well.

Answer (score 0):

VMT is a type usually used to allocate heap blocks of VMT size. The pointer to VMT is not VLA.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( const int argc, char * const argv[argc])
{
    typedef char * VMT [argc] ;

    VMT * vmt_ptr = malloc(sizeof(VMT));

    * vmt_ptr[0] = argv[0] ;

    free(vmt_ptr);

   return 42;
}
```

Some people prefer to call them "VLA on the heap". For some people that defeats the purpose of VLAs.  For them, VLA is a small(er) array on the stack.

```
 { // VMT is a type of VLA
   VMT VLA  ;
       VLA[0] = argv[0] ;
 }
```

No mem leak here. But then some people are wondering what the fuss is all about.

```
{
    typedef char * VMT [argc] ;

    VMT * vmt_ptr = alloca(sizeof(VMT));

    * vmt_ptr[0] = argv[0] ;
}
```

They are using alloca, using the VMTs in the process. Effectively creating VMT pointers to blocks allocated on stack space.

There are valid use cases for all three snippets. I hope also showing what are the VMT's.

Mandatory Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zGe4K5hez

Comment: (1) `alloca` is mostly obsolete, you should simply use VLAs instead. Using `alloca` as you show is completely useless. (2) Your `vmt_ptr` variable is a pointer to an array (yes, this is possible, and it can be very very useful actually), so you should write `(*vmt_ptr)[0]` to access the first element. Here, this is the same just because you ask for index 0.